# Importing bookmarks from Pale Moon to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How do I import bookmarks from Pale Moon 15.4.1 to Google Chrome v24? There is no option for Pale Moon in the tab that opens when I select Bookmarks -> Import bookmarks and settings...

I'm running Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. From Pale Moon/Firefox's `Bookmarks menu / Show All Bookmarks / Import and Backup` select **Export Bookmarks to HTML**
2. From the Chrome Menu [image: 1] select `Bookmark manager / Organize / Import bookmarks` to select and import the HTML file saved previously

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will create an Imported folder on the Toolbar and an Imported  directory for all the bookmarks. You will need to use the Chrome Bookmark Manager to rearrange the imported bookmarks where you want them by dragging them.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It asks how to import the bookmarks **not** how to rearrange then when they are imported.